# Photoshop cs5 query

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5

How to draw multiple lines in a circular format in photoshop cs5? For reference, http://www.freshbox.com.au/ the green bars in the background is what I wish to achieve.

Comment: Maybe there's a better forum; even http://superuser.com/ doesn't seem quite right for "how do I use an Adobe application?" kind of question, but it seems more likely to know than SO...

Comment: you can do it in Illustrator

Comment: Yea, but I already have my file in photoshop, can I transfer it over to illustrator and edit it there?

Comment: [Sun Rays Brush](http://memmus.deviantart.com/art/Memmus-Brush-Pack-Sun-Ray-45507476) For everyone, looking to do this faster.

Answer (score 1):

You do it by drawing multiple parallel lines with spaces in between and then use filter->distort->polar coordinates->rectangular to polar

Comment: Should all the line be on the same layer?

Comment: @Merstzik Hey, that's not how I'm looking to do it. I've posted a link for reference.

Comment: yes they should. What is more it's better to avoid having this lines to touch the left and right edge of the workspace.

Comment: @Merstzik I did what you asked me to do, but the result is not how I'm want it to be.

Comment: for reference: [before](http://i741.photobucket.com/albums/xx60/Pjurczynski/example-1.jpg) and [after](http://i741.photobucket.com/albums/xx60/Pjurczynski/example_fin.jpg)

Comment: @Merstzik Yea, my bad, I drew horizontal parallel lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Sun Rays Brush](http://memmus.deviantart.com/art/Memmus-Brush-Pack-Sun-Ray-45507476) For everyone, looking to do this faster.

Comment: nice alternative for those lazy ones ;). That really helps having even rays - which I always had a problem of.